# HTML Link doesn't work properly sometimes

Tags: html, hyperlink

I am using a local server for my applications and sometimes when I created a button or a link to another page in a new tab, it turns out to not working properly. It's not always like this, but sometimes, might sound silly. I give example below.

Let's say my application is `**programmingworld**` which exists in **www** folder, then in `index.html` file, I create a link for a button like this

```
<a href="www.google.co.uk"  ><div class="button" id="button=popup">Download Codes</div></a>
```

When I open it in a browser and click the button, sometimes it goes to `http://localhost/programmingworld/www.google.co.uk` where nothing is displayed on the page. It supposed to be `www.google.co.uk` in the new tab where I can see the google homepage.

Can you please tell me why?

Comment: make sure you put the http: or https  in front of the link, it's looking for a relative link

Comment: Yea I got it and thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write:

```
<a href="http://www.google.co.uk"  ><div class="button" id="button=popup">Download Codes</div></a>
```

If you didn't write http:// at the the beginning of the hyperlink, it will be search you your local directories or files.

Answer (score 2):

To make sure that the link goes to where you intend and not where it goes try adding `//` or `http://`.

Example:
`<a href="//www.google.com/">Google</a>`
or
`<a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>`

With `//` it will try http and https.

Comment: I've tried to just put `://` but it didn't work but it works when I put `http://` Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh okay, I guess it doesn't work all the time.  Might be browser dependent.

Comment: I think so, would be using the method next time :)

Comment: I've tried to just put `//google.co.uk` and it works.

Comment: Ah, yes.  It's not with the `:`.  I'll fix my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `https://` before www.google.co.uk

So you're markup should look like this:

```html
<a href="https://www.google.co.uk">
  <div class="button" id="button=popup">Download Codes</div>
</a>
```

you can also do it like this (no `https`):

```html
<a href="//google.co.uk">
  <div class="button" id="button=popup">Download Codes</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't included the protocol in your URL. it must start with either http:// or https://

Also, remove the div from inside the anchor tag.

Your question suggests that you need to do a little bit more testing on basic html.

Comment: div inside a tag is fine in html5 as long as there are no interactive elements, html was a no no though

Answer (score -1):

I would most definitely suggest using https://
I've had similar problems such as that, and in order to fix them try adding https.

Comment: what if it's not https link ?

Comment: I've checked your link and it does work. My browser automatically add the "https":  https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl
try using that ^ it should work.

Comment: google might only be used as an example in this case, try [W3schools with https](https://www.w3schools.com/)

Comment: only sites with a ssl cert, otherwise you get insecure warnings or no site at all, some secure sites will let you do certain things on a http version of their site